# How to get email from selected ABPerson in ABPeoplePickerView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, abpeoplepickerview

I need to access selected person's e-mail from my Cocoa application. I've placed ABPeoplePickerView onto main window and got a list of selected persons via `[peoplePicker selectedRecords]`. How do I access E-mail field of `ABPerson` object?

Answer (score 2):

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
     shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
                               property:(ABPropertyID)property 
                             identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    NSString *email = nil;
    ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    if(emails){
        email = (NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails,0);
        [email autorelease];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    emaillabel.text = email;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: There is an error in your code. If you have 3 email addresses you always get the 1st one. You should use "identifier" instead of 0 as 2nd param to ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `ABPerson` object is referenced by `person`:

```
ABRecordCopyValue( ( ABRecordRef ) person, kABEmailProperty );
```